# get the html element after created

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm creating a img when i click in a input, then i get the html or anyelse from the created img.

but i dont know why this is not working!

always return `null`

my js:

```
$("#click").click(function(){
    var $imgDone = $('<img/>').attr('src', 'someImage/insomewhere.jpg');
    $(this).after($imgDone);
    setTimeout(function(){
          alert($(this).next().html());
    }, 1000);
});
```

i mande a exp.: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/frGpx/14/)

Comment: Besides what others are explaining, calling `.html()` on an `img` element will not return anything anyways. It is a simple tag, has no content.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to find the `<img>` with `$(this).next()` when you've already found it -- `$imgDone`?

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski: becase i have more then one img and diferent places.

Comment: but the variable `$imgDone` when accessed in the callback will still be the one you just created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is pointing at the wrong place in `setInterval`.

The `this` you have in the outer scope isn't the same as the `this` that you get inside the callback, which will usually be the `window` object, since:

```
setInterval(f, t)
```

is actually

```
window.setInterval(f, t);
```

To solve the problem, take a copy of `this` in the outer scope:

```
$("#click").click(function(){
    var self = this;
    var $imgDone = $('<img/>').attr('src', 'someImage/insomewhere.jpg');
    $(this).after($imgDone);
    setTimeout(function(){
          alert($(self).next().html());
    }, 1000);
});
```

For efficiency, as @T.J. Crowder suggests, you could actually use the jQuery constructor to take that copy, and save yourself a few calls to jQuery:

```
$("#click").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $imgDone = $('<img/>')
         .attr({src:  'someImage/insomewhere.jpg'})
         .insertAfter(this); // NB: not $this here

    setTimeout(function(){
          alert($this.next().html());
    }, 1000);
});
```

The other problem is that `.html()` shows the *inner* contents of tags, not the tags themselves, and your `img` tag has no inner contents.

There doesn't appear to be any builtin jQuery method that returns the actual whole HTML of an element.  To do that you'd need to put your element into something else (e.g. a `<div>`) and then take the `.html()` of *that*.

Here's a plugin I just made that does this, inspired by something [I found via Google](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/msg/62a2e93f55119d48%3C/a%3E?pli=1):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.outerhtml = function() {
        return $('<div/>').append(this.clone()).html();
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Demo of it in use on your problem at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/qaSmS/

Comment: +1, but just start with `var $this = $(this);` and then use that throughout. That removes an unnecessary call to `$()` while creating the variable for the closure, and increases clarity by referring to same thing in *one* way rather than...two? three?

Answer (score 2):

because the timeout function is called form a different context, `this` no longer applies.

```
$("#click").click(function(){
    var $imgDone = $('<img/>').attr('src', 'someImage/insomewhere.jpg');
    $(this).after($imgDone);
    myImg = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
          alert($(myImg).next().html());
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: No need to call `$()` on `myImg` again.

Answer (score 0):

The ".html()" method gets the **contents** of something, **not including** the markup for the container itself.

The other answers indicating that the use of `this` in the timeout handler are correct, of course.  When you fix that, however, the alert will just be empty.