# Save DOMobject as String

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a DOMelement like

text

and I have saved this in a variable elem in a function

```
function(elem){ var elem=elem; }
```

And NOW I want to save this dom object as a string like

```
<div class="testdiv"><div class="delete">text</div>
```

How would you manage this? I tried sth. like `elem.toString()`
which didn't work or `elem.html()` which just returns the INNER html.

Comment: maybe you're looking for outerHTML property 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588482/get-the-html-content-of-clicked-element-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For jQuery you might want to refer it as

```
var elem = $('#elem');
var strElem = elem[0].outerHTML;
if(strElem == null) {
    strElem = $('<div>').append(elem.clone()).html();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KRgkc/3/

Comment: oh my..ok this works as well as the example above, BUT NOT in Firefox 8 as it seems! it works for chrome, safari..but not for ff! how can this be.... :-(

Comment: @ho.s the FF approach is to clone `elem`, append it to a created from scratch `div`, and return the html of that div ;). Otherwise, `outerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want the [outer html](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.outerHTML):

```
elem.outerHTML
```

Comment: thx, but..hm..as for the reason I get the element by `var elem= anotherelem.parent('.classname')` the outerHTML property is not defined for this? is there a jquery method for outerHTML?

Comment: hm, when I click on the link, the alert says "undefined"

Comment: seems as if it just don't work for firefox, but I need to support ff. bummer!

Comment: Hey @ho.s check out this answer for a much more complete solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/3819589/724626