# Get the complete value of $(this) including tags and attributes in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of elements with data attributes:

```
<span data-product_attribute="title" data-product_id="12">product title</span>
<span data-product_attribute="vendor" data-product_id="12">product vendor</span>
```

And I'm using a jQuery selector to grab them and put them in a list for processing:

```
$('span[data-product_attribute]').map(function() {
    var o = {};
    o.name = $(this).attr("data-product_attribute");
    o.value = $(this).html(); // ** this line is not what I want **
    return o;
}).get()
```

The `html()` method only returns what's contained inside the `<span>` tag, but what I want is the whole thing. i.e. I'm trying to get it to do this:

```
o.value = '<span data-product_attribute="title" data-product_id="12">product title</span>'
```

Is there a jQuery method that will return everything that is represented by `$(this)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the "outerhtml" of the element.  Some browsers can provide this via the `.outerHTML` property.

Failing that, there's a trivial plugin for this in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6509421/6782) to a related question:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.outerhtml = function() {
        return $('<div/>').append(this.clone()).html();
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Example HTML:

```
 <div id="testing">
    <span data-product_attribute="title" data-product_id="12">product title</span>
    <span data-product_attribute="vendor" data-product_id="12">product vendor</span>
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
 function getHtml(elem) {
     var tmp = $('<div />');
     tmp.append(elem);
     return $(tmp).html();
 }    

 $('span[data-product_attribute]').map(function() {
     var o = {};
     o.name = $(this).attr("data-product_attribute");
     o.value = getHtml($(this));
     alert(o.value);
     return o;
 }).get()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through JavaScript quite easily with:

```
$(this).get(0).outerHTML;
```

You can this plugin if necessary:

```
$.fn.outerHTML = function(){
    return (!this.length) ? this : (this[0].outerHTML || (
      function(el){
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
          var contents = div.innerHTML;
          div = null;
          return contents;
    })(this[0]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
$('#mydiv').on('click', function(){
    console.log(this.outerHTML);
});
```

see this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PM8sK/2/)